# how to hide navigation bar + toolbar and change tableView height on scroll

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've got a view controller embedded in a navigation controller with a toolbar attached under it so it has this style:  [image]

as you can see with my storyboard, i also have a container view with a tableviewcontroller inside:

[image]

on scroll, i need to hide the navigation bar which I've been able to do.  The problem is, I have to also hide the toolbar that is under the nav bar as well as expand the height of the table view so that when the nav bar and toolbar both disappear, the table view can use the extra space.

Comment: Please post some code not just pictures. Also what have you tried already?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a container view for your tableView, and not just having your Main View Controller conform to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`? I think it might simply your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have perfect answer but try to use below code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
will help you..

you did not mentioned weather your code is in objective C/ Swift. I am providing you Both ::

> Obj-C

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

> Swift

```
self.navigationController().setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

For tabBar, If you want to hide tabBar with navigationBar use this thing..[image: use this]

Or use this for tabBar hide >

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
detailViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];    
[detailViewController release];
```